# How to identify UItextFields without using tag.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Im creating different UITextField for different type of input(date,picker etc).
Im already using tag to identify different textFields of each type.

how can i identify textfield without tag.
Can i assign string identifier to textFields?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `CATEGORY`, Create any string method like **stringTag** etc. You problem is solved.

Or

You can use `UITextField's attributedText, placeholder` properties to store **String Tag** for identification. But make sure HIDE them after assigning **"String TAG"**
This is not recommended solution but it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only identify them by using tags.

Maybe you can use 1000, 2000, 3000 for types, and 1, 2, 3, for identifying.

So tag 1001 is the first in category 1000, 1100 is the 100th in category 1000 etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare UITextField with their outlet if you have created. You can assign string identifier to textFields as bellow

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char kTextFieldAssociatedKey;

objc_setAssociatedObject(yourTextField,
                         &kTextFieldAssociatedKey,
                         aStrKey,
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);




- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *aStrKey = objc_getAssociatedObject(textField, &kTextFieldAssociatedKey);
    objc_removeAssociatedObjects(textField);
    NSLog(@"%@", aStrKey);
    return [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: what is aString here?

Comment: aStrKey is any string which you want to give as identifier

Answer (score 0):

Another way to identify textfield without Tag is

```
NSArray *arySubViews=[self.view subviews];

for (int i=0;i<arySubViews.count; i++){

    id subObj= [arySubViews objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([subObj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        /// At this place you identify your Text Field without tag

        // you can identify through Title or etc.
        UITextField *tfObj=(UITextField*)subObj;    
     }
}
```

[Source code as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVtS3.png)

Comment: Your code will only differentiate whether it is textfield or label etc. Question is different.